# GCloud VM error: Error from HTTP-over-RPC proxy: No response

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app to a python Google Appengine application. The Node.js app is a custom runtime module, hosted in a Google Compute Engine VM.
I'm able to test it in localhost without any errors, but when I deploy to AppEngine and load a webpage, I get:

> Error from HTTP-over-RPC proxy: No response

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your app isn't responding to proxied requests.

The way that Managed VMs work is that your app runs inside a Docker container on a Google Compute Engine VM. This VM also runs a proxy that will direct external traffic on the appropriate port to the Docker container running your app. This error message indicates that there was no response from your app.

One possible cause is that your app is listening on the wrong port: are you respecting the `$PORT` environment variable?

You should also take a look at your application logs:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project>/appengine/logs
```

---

Take a look at the [node.js "Hello World" app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/1-hello-world) for an basic example with the ports correctly configured. Here's a relevant excerpt:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || '8080',
                        '0.0.0.0',
                        function() {    
  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s',
              server.address().address,
              server.address().port);
  console.log("Press Ctrl+C to quit.");    
});
```